# Jira python runs very slowly, any ideas on why?

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I'm using jira-python to automate a bunch of tasks in Jira. One thing that I find weird is that jira-python takes a long time to run. It seems like it's loading or something before sending the requests. I'm new to python, so I'm a little confused as to what's actually going on. Before finding jira-python, I was sending requests to the Jira REST API using the requests library, and it was blazing fast (and still is, if I compare the two). Whenever I run the scripts that use jira-python, there's a good 15 second delay while 'loading' the library, and sometimes also a good 10-15 second delay sending each request.

Is there something I'm missing with python that could be causing this issue? Anyway to keep a python script running as a service so it doesn't need to 'load'  the library each time it's ran?

Comment: Show us the code. But from my experience, when I use jira-python the bottleneck seems to be Jira processing data. I am usually able to create issues like 1 per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ThePavoIC, you seem to be correct. I notice MASSIVE changes in speed if Jira has been restarted and re-indexed recently. Scripts that would take a couple minutes to run would complete in seconds. Basically, you need to make sure Jira is tuned for performance and keep your indexes up to date.